# Dynamic array "default constructed elements" c++

Tags: c++, arrays, default

I need to make a dyanmic array. I have got this constructor function prototype. `ExArray(int);` with `indivdual elements must be default constructed`. What does it mean when it wants the elements to be default constructed? Does it want the element to be initialised in the default constructor and not in this constructor?

Comment: I'd suggest to clarify assignment requirements with your teacher, not SO.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the class constructor is for the `ExArray` class.  But this is a container class which holds other objects (similar to `std::vector` for instance).  In order to have a `ExArray` of size 10, for instance, that contains instances of class `X`, a reasonable requirement is to make `X` have a default constructor.  This way, each of the 10 items in the container will be default constructed.  Otherwise, it gets hard to define `ExArray` since one would have to supply constructor arguments to the class it contains.

Answer (score 0):

In a static array like `std::array<T,n> arr` or C-style `T arr[n]`, C++ automatically calls the default constructor (`T::T()`) on each element of the array when the array is constructed. When the array is deleted it calls the destructor of each element.

A dynamic array like `std::vector` (where elements can be appended/removed) needs to handle this manually when elements are added. For example:

```
T* elements = static_cast<T*>( std::malloc(n * sizeof(T)) );
for(std::ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    new (&elements[i]) T();
```

Allocates raw memory for `n` elements, and casts the pointer into a pointer to uninitialized `T` elements. Then it manually calls the default constructor of each element.

Using placement new to initialize the object/call the constructor. The destructor can be called like `elements[i].~T()`.

Comment: Note that `elements[i].T();` is not valid C++.  The real code would do something like `new (&elements[i]) T();`